# How to define a Many-To-Many relationship to another app?

Tags: django, many-to-many, relationships

I have two apps:
Ads
Domains

An Ad can be associated via Many-To-Many to a Domain. In my Ad model I have put:

```
domains = models.ManyToManyField(Domain)
```

How do I make it so it uses the Domains app and not the Ads app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for even asking this all I had to do was do an import of the apps model:

```
from domains.models import Domain
```

Answer (score 5):

```
domains = models.ManyToManyField('app.Domain')
```

"**app**" is name of app contain domain